# Composer package could not be found

Tags: php, composer-php

Ok Composer is doing my head in.

I have created a test Package and have pushed to github. When I am trying to bring in that package I am getting error: The requested package weblee/travelparkingapps could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

The package composer file is

`{
    "name": "weblee/travelparkingapps",
    "description" : "TravelParkingApps Library ",
    "keywords": ["parking", "api"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name" : "Lee Smith",
            "email" : "lee@weblee.co.uk",
            "homepage" : "https://github.com/weblee/",
            "role" : "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php" : ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "4.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TravelParkingApps\\": "src"
        }
    }
}`

My local composer file is:

`{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "weblee/travelparkingapps": "0.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Apm\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish your package to [packagist](https://packagist.org/). Only committing to GitHub does not make it publicly available.

Comment: My Package is availble on the packagist , but still face the same error